# I want to create Div-Elements in Div-Containers using jquery (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to create 10 Div-Containers, which contain 10 Div Elements.
Therefor i have written the following code in TypeScript using jquery:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var outsidediv = $('<div id="outsidediv"></div>').appendTo('body')
        for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        }
        var innerdiv = $('<div class="innerdiv"></div>').appendTo('outsidediv');
    }
})
```

But all it does, is that it creates 10 Div Containers and one Div Element, which isn't inside a container.
I'd really appreciate if someone could take a quick look at this (normally) easy problem.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The parameter to appendTo should be a selector or an element or a jQuery object. You've given it strings here. $('body') instead of body, and outsidediv instead of 'outsidediv' should do it. http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var outsidediv = $('<div id="outsidediv' + i +'" class="outsidediv" />').appendTo('body');
    
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      var innerdiv = $('<div class="innerdiv"/>').appendTo('.outsidediv:last-child');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I really think, that i can work with your solution, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Append the `.innerdiv` already inside its container `#outsidediv` in one go by creating a single string of HTML and appending that to the body.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var div = '<div id="outsidediv">' + 
                  '<div class="innerdiv"></div>' + 
                  '<div class="innerdiv"></div>' + 
                  '<div class="innerdiv"></div>' + 
                  '<div class="innerdiv"></div>' + 
                  '<div class="innerdiv"></div>' + 
                  '<div class="innerdiv"></div>' + 
                  '<div class="innerdiv"></div>' + 
                  '<div class="innerdiv"></div>' + 
                  '<div class="innerdiv"></div>' + 
                  '<div class="innerdiv"></div>' + 
                  '</div>';
         $('body').append(div);
    }
})
```

Comment: Somehow i have the same output than before: 10 Containers (outsidediv) and one (innerdiv)..

Comment: I don't see how that is possible, only thing I can think of is your previous script has been cached. Clear your cache, refresh the page, try again

Comment: Ok, i think your code is running now, but it creates just 10 Containers with one div in each container, but i need 10 divs in each container..

Comment: Ah, misunderstood that part of your question. I've edited the answer accordingly, each container will have 10 inner divs.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't take a close look at what's going on but what jumps out at me straight away is your 2nd for loop is not doing anything as your 'innerdiv' variable is below where it closes.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $('<div id="outsidediv"></div>').appendTo('body');
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
       $('<div class="innerdiv"</div>').appendTo('outsidediv');
    }
  }
```

However fixing this wont work because jquery won't know which 'outsidediv' to append to.  You are going to have to think of a different approach. Perhaps just output the html you want?

```
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  html += '<div id="outsidediv">';
  for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    html += '<div class="innerdiv"</div>';
  }
  html += '</div>';
}
$(html).appendTo('body');
```

It's not the shortest way to do it but it should do what you want.